# How do I filter from plain text output

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running `wsl -l -v` to get a list of WSL VMs on my computer and I get a list like this:

```
NAME             STATE     VERSION
Ubuntu-18-04     Stopped   2
Ubuntu-20-04     Running   2
```

I only want to see the ones that are running.
I tried:

```
wsl -l -v | Select-Object NAME
```

but I just get a list of blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just found this in --help docs

```
wsl -l --running
```

output:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default)
```

Comment: I should have checked `wsl -?`!

Comment: it was under --list -l for me

Comment: Yes it was. I had missed it!

Answer (score 2):

While your specific use-case can be handled by `wsl --list --running` (as mentioned by [@X-*-FARZA_D-*-X's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74418676/11810933)), there are two reasons why your *filter* wasn't working:

First, you probably were looking for `Select-String Running`.  PowerShell's `Select-Object` would require a PowerShell *object* with a `NAME` property.  All `wsl.exe` provides is a string output.

But more importantly, it still won't work even after the proper:

```
wsl -l -v | Select-String Running
```

This is due to a bug in `wsl.exe` that causes it output as a mangled UTF-16.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72766085/11810933) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72324672/11810933) answer for details.

Given your use-case, you should be able to properly filter with:

```
$console = ([console]::OutputEncoding)
[console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
wsl -l -v | Select-String Running
[console]::OutputEncoding = $console
```

Alternatively, if you are using a recent release of WSL (0.64.0 or later) on Windows 11, you could simply:

```
$env:WSL_UTF8=1
wsl -l -v | Select-String Running
```